# how to set dynamic domains and subdomains in /etc/hosts

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache-config, ipconfig

in /etc/hosts file

```
127.0.0.1 admin.localhost    
127.0.0.1 school1.admin.localhost   
127.0.0.1 school2.admin.localhost  
127.0.0.1 school3.admin.localhost  
127.0.0.1 school4.admin.localhost  
127.0.0.1 school5.admin.localhost
```

I want to replace school1-school2 with a text so that it will support all the dynamic domains,like

```
127.0.0.1 admin.localhost     
127.0.0.1 {%something_like_that%}.admin.localhost
```